# Disable popup on add to cart button of virtuemart component in JOOMLA 1.7

Tags: php, virtuemart, joomla1.7

I am using Virtuemart 2.0.0 shopping cart component for JOOMLA 1.7. On flypage (product detail page) there a button "Add to Cart" for add product in cart.

When click on that button a popup box is open, popup box contains some option and details like product name, continue shopping button and go to checkout.

I want disable that popup box on add to cart button when i click that button page is redirect to checkout page.

So, anybody give me any idea to disable the popup and where i got that option in configuration of virtuemart on admin side

Answer (score 1):

One way is to modify the function that is in the vmprices.js file, and comment out the lines that show the popup, if you want you can add some other behavior right there, the function is sendtocart. For example to remove the popup should do this.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.product = function(options) {

    this.each(function(){
        var cart = $(this),
        addtocart = cart.find('input.addtocart-button'),
        plus   = cart.find('.quantity-plus'),
        minus  = cart.find('.quantity-minus'),
        select = cart.find('select'),
        radio = cart.find('input:radio'),
        virtuemart_product_id = cart.find('input[name="virtuemart_product_id[]"]').val(),
        quantity = cart.find('.quantity-input');

        **//addtocart.click(function(e) { 
            //sendtocart(cart);
            //return false;
        //});**

        plus.click(function() {
            var Qtt = parseInt(quantity.val());
            if (Qtt != NaN) {
                quantity.val(Qtt + 1);
            }
        });
        minus.click(function() {
            var Qtt = parseInt(quantity.val());
            if (Qtt != NaN && Qtt>0) {
                quantity.val(Qtt - 1);
            }
        });
        select.change(function() {
            $.setproducttype(cart,virtuemart_product_id);
        });
        radio.change(function() {
            $.setproducttype(cart,virtuemart_product_id);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if those settings still exists in 1.7 but it used to be under:

> **Components->VirtueMart->Admin-> Configuration->Site**

Click on the Configuration link underneath the "Select theme" for your Shop drop-down menu. There set the following values:

> **Customer Checkout in a popup (GreyBox)?** No
>
> **Use Ajax to add, update or delete products from the cart?** No

Answer (score 0):

VM 2.0 no longer uses themes so there is not changing any setting for the theme any more. If you want to change how any of the pages looks or works, you use a simple template override like you do for other Joomla extensions.

Copy this file -

```
components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php
```

Place the copy here -

```
YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php
```

Make any changes you want then.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify the function that is in the vmprices.js file, and comment out the lines that show the popup, if you want you can add some other behavior right there, the function is sendtocart. For example to remove the popup should do this.

```
function sendtocart(form){

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })
        var datas = form.serialize();
        $.getJSON(siteurl+'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json',encodeURIComponent(datas),
            function(datas, textStatus) {
                if(datas.stat ==1){
                    //var value = form.find('.quantity-input').val() ;
                    var txt = form.find(".pname").val()+' '+vmCartText;
                                            $.facebox.settings.closeImage = closeImage;
                                            $.facebox.settings.loadingImage = loadingImage;
                                            $.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml = faceboxHtml;
                    //$.facebox({ text: datas.msg +"<H4>"+txt+"</H4>" }, 'my-groovy-style');
                } else if(datas.stat ==2){
                    var value = form.find('.quantity-input').val() ;
                    var txt = form.find(".pname").val();
                                            $.facebox.settings.closeImage = closeImage;
                                            $.facebox.settings.loadingImage = loadingImage;
                                            $.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml = faceboxHtml;
                    //$.facebox({ text: datas.msg +"<H4>"+txt+"</H4>" }, 'my-groovy-style');
                } else {
                                            $.facebox.settings.closeImage = closeImage;
                                            $.facebox.settings.loadingImage = loadingImage;
                                            $.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml = faceboxHtml;
                    //$.facebox({ text: "<H4>"+vmCartError+"</H4>"+datas.msg }, 'my-groovy-style');
                }
                if ($(".vmCartModule")[0]) {
                    $(".vmCartModule").productUpdate();
                }
            });
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way is to uncheck the 'use product script' box in Configuration > Templates.

Then in your product detail template change:

```
<noscript><input type="hidden" name="task" value="add" /></noscript>
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="add" />
```

removing the noscript tags

Answer (score 0):

go to virtuemart components and look left side bar select second last configuration tab and open configuration tab and look at upper some tab their select checkout tab look in that tab some option their first option disable popup for the go to cart.